# What does the code @TypeConverterAnnotation mean?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code is from a webpage, I can't understand that the code @TypeConverterAnnotation mean?

Is it just a annotation, can I delete the code?

```
package mobi.porquenao.poc.kotlin.core

import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.converter.TypeConverter
import java.util.*
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.TypeConverter as TypeConverterAnnotation

@TypeConverterAnnotation
class CalendarConverter : TypeConverter<Long, Calendar>() {

    override fun getDBValue(model: Calendar): Long? {
        return model.timeInMillis
    }

    override fun getModelValue(data: Long?): Calendar {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = data!!
        return calendar
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is **just** an annotation from *[DBFlow project](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow)*:

```
/**
 * Author: andrewgrosner
 * Description: Marks a class as being a TypeConverter. 
 * A type converter will turn a non-model, non-SQLiteTyped class into
 * a valid database type.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface TypeConverter {

    /**
     * @return Specify a set of subclasses by which the {@link TypeConverter} 
     * registers for. For each one, this will create a new instance of the converter.
     */
    Class<?>[] allowedSubtypes() default {};
}
```

How can we know if you need it in your code or not? :)